# How to show Month on x axes and Day on footer label for Matplotlib with ipympl backend

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I'm using JupiterLab with ipymlp and basically I want to print month at x axes and month and day in footer (while mouse is hovering over plot).
So is there any way to modify either one of them and not affect another?

Here is example with highlighted issue.
[image: Current behavior]
Desired behavior would be like this
[image: Desired behavior]

My current code is

```py
%matplotlib widget

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))

# Drawing max and min lines with custom tuned palette
date_index = np.arange('2015-01-01','2016-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')

plt.plot(date_index, stats['max_temp'], '-', linewidth=1, color='#ffbcaf')
plt.plot(date_index, stats['min_temp'], '-', linewidth=1, color='#a5d5d8')

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d %b'))
```

Obviously if I'm changing last line to this

```py
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

Axes labels are ok, but footer is showing month and not showing day of month.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hack, but idea is that widget is reading from major ticks, so we need to show minor ticks on plot and hide major ones.

Instead of

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d %b'))
```

We showing minor and hiding major by

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d %b'))
```

And hiding minor ticks (if needed)

```
plt.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False, labelleft=True, labelbottom=True, which='minor')
```